# Sql filter and or statement within C# application

Tags: c#, sql, .net, collections, ado.net

I have a C# application in which i have this problem : when i run this snippet:

**First Way**

```
public void GetList(List<string> liste, List<int> outliste)
{
    foreach( string s in liste){
        outliste.Add(SqlFunction(s));
    }
}
public int SqlFunction(string str)
{
    string query = "select id from user where name="+str;
    ...................
    // return the id
}
```

the execution time is 51 sec

**Second Way**

```
public void SqlSecondWayFunction(List<string> liste, List<int> outliste)
{

   string query ="select id from user where (";
   foreach(string str in liste){
       query += "name=" str + "or  ";
   }
   query += " 1=0 )";

   ...................
   // fill outliste by the result of the query
}
```

The execution time is 1m:19sec!!!!!!!!! ( the count of the `liste` is about 11000).

So i need to know why the first way is faster?

Comment: You know both of them are open to SQL Injection ?

Comment: @user2711965 Thanks i know that, it is just a quick sample

Comment: Where exactly is the bottleneck?  Is it in the code where you construct the query, or in the SQL server when the query is executed?  When you extract the runtime-built query and execute it manually on the SQL server, what are the results?  You need to do at least *some* debugging for this.  Also, please be aware that this is *highly vulnerable* code for SQL injections.  You might consider moving to an ORM of some sort (such as Entity Framework) instead of manually building SQL commands, to address both the vulnerability and the performance.

Comment: the second example concatenates all where blocks and links them with `OR`. then at the end, you append an `1=1` to the where statement which is also `OR` linked. that means it returns all rows because `1=1` is true all the time

Comment: I'd rather want to know why the difference is so very small. A query with a condition that contains thousands of operators should take a lot longer to run...

Comment: I suspect the major problem in the second method is building your query using `query +=`, in each loop this creates a new string on the heap, rather than just adding to the existing string. Use a StringBuilder instead. Having said that there are much better and safer ways of passing a list as a parameter. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @GarethD Sql Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is faster because it's doing fewer things.  And it's only selecting a subset of records.

The second is slower because you're concatenating tons of strings (which is fairly slow to do) as well as performing thousands of unnecessary comparisons on the database for *every* record, only to return *every* record anyway.

Basically, you're asking the database to compare the `name` column against 11,000 strings for every record in the table.  If the table contains, for example, 100,000 records then you're making *1,100,000,000* string comparisons.  And then you return all of the records anyway because one of your conditions is "1 = 1" which is *always* true.

Comment: Thanks , i changed `1=1` ( see my edit) and i use string builder instead of string , i got this time 54 sec

Comment: @Lamloumi: Now it's returning fewer records.  But it's still performing a lot of string concatenations and string comparisons.  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: i'm asking why the first way still the fastest even i connect/close connection in every call of the method , in the second way only one time i filter the list to get the result and it is in DBMS side

Comment: ADO.NET uses [connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so even if you are opening/closing the connection in your code, the chances are that ADO.NET is able to reuse the same connection over and over again, so you are not actually getting the cost of opening and closing the connection 11,000 times.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- Adding a long list of OR's in your WHERE clause is generally not very efficient, due to the time it takes to first parse a very long query string, and moreover the internal work done by the database engine for long lists of OR's
- The last part you add (" OR 1=1") makes the WHERE clause ALWAYS TEST TRUE! It's the same as not having a WHERE clause at all
- Either of the above could result in your first example of many simple queries taking less time than one inefficient large query
- You should consider one of the following for your use case: 1) get the list of id's by loading a DataTable with "select id from user", calling the DataTable.AsEnumerable() method, and then joining to your other List using a LINQ query, 2) loading the list into a database table first and then using SQL to join the user table to your list, or 3) loading the list into a comma-separated list of strings and using SQL's IN operator in place of your name=x OR name=y OR name=z construct.

Answer (score 1):

Use [table-valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you want to pass a list to SQL Server 2008. On your database you will first need to create a new TYPE:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ListOfInt AS TABLE(Value INT);
```

You can then use this as a parameter, something like:

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));

for (int i = 0; i < liste.Count; i++)
{
    var row = table.NewRow();
    row[0] = liste[i];
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}

string sql = "SELECT ID FROM [User] WHERE ID IN (SELECT Value FROM @Liste)";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Your connection String"))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    var tvp = new SqlParameter("@Liste", SqlDbType.Structured).TypeName = "ListOfInt";
    tvp.Value = table;
    command.Parameters.Add(tvp);
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        outliste.Add(reader.GetInt("ID"));
    }
}
```